# Picasa for Linux: doesn't it support video files?

Tags: linux, video, import, picasa

I'm just switching from Windows to Linux. I'm glad to see that Picasa is also available (v3.0 beta), but **doesn't Picasa on Linux support video files?** [This official help page](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=19496) doesn't mention Linux...

I've just imported some files from my camera, but Picasa skipped all the videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1385837   for a solution. I've followed this, and works well. :)

Comment: Wow, convoluted but helpful! I'm now even more baffled that it's missing by default, now that dedicated people have proved that it can be done.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the Linux version, that's the Windows version of Picasa you need to run, isn't it? Otherwise why the Wine emulation?

Answer (score 7):

Due to licensing issues, Picasa on Linux does not support videos at all.

From the [FAQ](http://picasa.google.com/linux/faq.html):

> Q: Hey! I have a bunch of movie files
>   that Picasa skipped.
>
> Picasa for Linux does not support
>   movie files. The program will not
>   attempt to find or play movies. (Note:
>   under Options > File Types, the Movies
>   checkbox is visible but not
>   functional.)

Comment: WhAT?!?!? o_O That's incredible... what a showstopper! Thanks for pointing out that information; I hadn't looked in the FAQ, and I was searching for "video", not "movies".